# Cannot delete files/directories

Tags: node.js, npm, snowpack, astrojs

I just started a blog template project with Astro.
https://astro.build/

My project folder is C:/web/astro-test-1/ and i want to deploy my build to a local server at C:/wamp64/www/astro/ with `npm run build`.

I´d setup the astro.config.mjs as following:

```
dist: './../../wamp64/www/astro'
```

**This build only works if the folder doesn't already exist.**

My error:

```
[build] Error: Cannot delete files/directories outside the current working directory. Can be overridden with the `force` option.
```

**Where and how do a set the `force` option?**

Comment: I tried the same but i didn't get any issues

Comment: Have you tried to rebuild when the folder is already created?